# Workspace.Arrow.StandGiver:38: attempt to index nil with 'Destroy'

Tags: lua

My goal was that when you click on the Arrow, the folder in Players instead of Stand1 should change to Stand2 but this does not happen.
Tried to solve but nothing helps.

Error in this line:

> prevStand:Destroy()

```
local Arrow = script.Parent
local Click = Arrow:WaitForChild("Click")

Click.MouseClick:Connect(function(player)

    local Backpack = player:FindFirstChild("Backpack")
    if Backpack then
        local Stands = game:GetService("ServerStorage"):WaitForChild("Stands")

        local PlrStats = player:WaitForChild("PlrStats")
        local currentStand = PlrStats:WaitForChild("Stand")

        local randomStand = math.random(1,2)
        if randomStand == 1 then
            --Give Stand1
            if Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand1") or Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand2") then
                local prevStand = workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name.." Stand")
                local prev = Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand1") or Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand2")
                prevStand:Destroy()
                prev:Destroy()

                local Stand = Stands:FindFirstChild("Stand1"):Clone()
                Stand.Parent = Backpack

                currentStand.Value = "Stand1"
            else
                local Stand = Stands:FindFirstChild("Stand1"):Clone()
                Stand.Parent = Backpack

                currentStand.Value = "Stand1"
            end

        elseif randomStand == 2 then
            --Give Stand2
            if Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand1") or Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand2") then
                local prevStand = workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name.."Stand")
                local prev = Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand1") or Backpack:FindFirstChild("Stand2")
                prevStand:Destroy()
                prev:Destroy()

                local Stand = Stands:FindFirstChild("Stand2"):Clone()
                Stand.Parent = Backpack

                currentStand.Value = "Stand2"
            else
                local Stand = Stands:FindFirstChild("Stand2"):Clone()
                Stand.Parent = Backpack

                currentStand.Value = "Stand2"
            end
        end
        Arrow:Destroy()
    end
end)
```

I have folders with Stand1 and Stand2 and idk how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Well if `prevStand` is nil, `workspace:FindFirstChild(player.Name.."Stand")` obviously returns nil.

This happens if there is no child with that name or in local scripts if that instance has not been replicated yet.

Try to use [WaitForChild](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild) instead.